# Multiple plots in one figure in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, figure

I have three plots and I want to show them in a figure like below

[link](https://www.r-bloggers.com/beyond-basic-r-plotting-with-ggplot2-and-multiple-plots-in-one-figure/)
[image]

I made a few attempts but I was not successful. My codes are given below:

```
dat <- read.table(text="
dates   PS.230  PS.286  PS.389
3.01.2018   20.75103    16.69312    -6.503637
15.01.2018  15.00284    16.03211    16.1058
8.02.2018   11.0789 7.438522    -2.970704
20.02.2018  15.10865    12.8969 3.935687
4.03.2018   24.74799    19.25148    9.186779
28.03.2018  -1.299456   7.028817    -8.126284
9.04.2018   4.778902    8.309322    -3.450085
21.04.2018  7.131915    9.484932    -4.326919


", header=T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dat$dates <- as.Date(dat$dates, "%d.%m.%Y")


library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

a <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=dates, y=PS.230)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = lm, size = 0.15, color = "#da0018") +  #cizgi eklemek icin
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months",date_labels = "%Y-%m",
               limits = as.Date.character(c("01/12/2017","31/12/2018"),
                                          format = "%d/%m/%Y")) +
  ylim(-20,40) +
  ylab("[mm/year]") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_linedraw() #theme_light
a + theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
  panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
)

b <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=dates, y=PS.286)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = lm, size = 0.15, color = "#da0018") +  #cizgi eklemek icin
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months",date_labels = "%Y-%m",
               limits = as.Date.character(c("01/12/2017","31/12/2018"),
                                          format = "%d/%m/%Y")) +
  ylim(-20,40) +
  ylab("[mm/year]") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_linedraw() #theme_light
b + theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
  panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
)

c <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=dates, y=PS.389)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = lm, size = 0.15, color = "#da0018") +  #cizgi eklemek icin
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 months",date_labels = "%Y-%m",
               limits = as.Date.character(c("01/12/2017","31/12/2018"),
                                          format = "%d/%m/%Y")) +
  ylim(-20,40) +
  ylab("[mm/year]") +
  xlab("") +
  theme_linedraw() #theme_light
c + theme(
  axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1),
  panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
  panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank()
)
```

in the link I provided, much better graphics were drawn with fewer lines. my codes seem a little more complicated and frankly i couldn't get out. a, b and c plots in one image and only one date axes. How can I modify the codes to achieve sample result? Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your dataframe here?  To do so, please post the output of `dput(dat)`.  From the looks of it, you have "wide" data, where it should be in tidy format.  In other words, `dat$PS.230`, `dat$PS.286`, and `dat$389` should be gathered into to columns: a key and a value.  This can be done via the `gather()` function from `dplyr`.  Then you can plot with `x=dates` and `y=value`, and use `face_grid()` to build the multiplot.  If you share your data, I can help with some code.

Comment: *sorry - that was `facet_grid()`, not `face_grid()`!

Comment: Thank you @chemdork123. I ran the dput(dat) command an the output is: 
  https://justpaste.it/3fwsf

Comment: There is something I want to say to clarify. There is 3 data in a chart as I give for example. but I want to show 1 piece of data in a chart. that is, only ps230 in the first chart, ps286 in the second chart and ps389 in the third chart. I think it is easier to understand when I look at this figure. https://ibb.co/rdL1fZK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for posting your data.  As mentioned, the first step is to arrange your dataset so that it is in [Tidy Data format](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  The information in `dat$PS.230`, `dat$PS.286` and `dat$PS.389` should be better represented in two columns:

1. *First Column: name of data type*  - We'll call this column `dat$value_type` and it will have values that indicate if `dat$results` comes from PS.230, PS.286, or PS.389.
2. *Second Column: value of data* - We'll call this column `dat$result` and it just shows the value.  This will be the `y=` aesthetic for all plots.

#### Pre-Processing: Gather into TidyData format

Use the `gather()` function to gather all columns in to a key ("value_type") and a "value" ("result").  We'll gather all columns except for "dates", so we just note to exclude that column via `-dates`:

```
dat <- dat %>% gather(key='value_type', value='result', -dates)
```

#### Plot

For the plot, you apply x and y aesthetics to "date" and "result".  You can use "value_type" to differentiate based on color and create your legend for points and lines.  You also use "value_type" as the column for creating the facets (the three separate plots) via use of `facet_grid()` function.  Note that `value_type ~ .` arranges by "value_type" vertically, whereas `. ~ value_type` would arrange horizontally:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x=dates, y=result)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=value_type)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=value_type)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 months', date_labels = '%Y-%m') +
  facet_grid(value_type ~ .) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: One more question if you are available please... If I want to plot more than one lines in PS.230 and others, how can I set codes and data structure? For example this data https://gofile.io/d/vHxJsE

Comment: Sorry, but I am unable to click on a gofile link, but the general idea would be to follow the same structure as the combined (gathered) dataset.  I would suggest adding a column that would differentiate the two lines in PS.230 - so like `dat$replicate <- 1` to make everything have 1 there, then you would add your new dataset where `dat$replicate` was 2 (or whatever).  The code remains the same except that you would need to include `group=replicate` in your `aes()` within `ggplot()` so that `geom_line` and `geom_point` know that these two should be considered separate lines.